# Study design - fresh look!

Tags: survival, expected-value, cox-model

Need to be advised outside of the circle.
I am more a physiologist+mathematician plus-c,c++,java coder/developer.

Chart data.
From year 2001 till 2012.
89 nursing stations or emergency call receptacles.
24 general medicine hospitals.
3 first level gun shot wound centres(hospitals)

There is a detailed database on each and every parameter taken let say every hour of the bleeding patient,
who was delivered  by ambulance into a general hospital for a surgical correction with second level surgical facility.

Also there is a bit more detailed database on patients who were delivered straight into a first level surgical hospital.

And there is a database of patients who were delivered
at first into a general medical hospital,
had been treated there unsuccessfully
but later were transferred into a first level surgical hospital.

The common parameters are continues bleeding, low haemoglobin and falling,
low blood pressure and falling,
high respiratory rate and rising, et etcetera.
So generally shock development would be he major concern.

I assumed time to event model and influencing causes on the way, cox model, what would you select?

Comment: You should try to clarify your variables and outcomes and what you are aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine the time to death/shock for your patients based on changing covariates (continues_bleeding, low_hgb_and_falling, etc.) and some fixed covariates (admission to ward/ER), you could use a set of time-dependent covariates within a Cox model.

Please describe your data more clearly and the aims of your research.